# KarmaJS Preload Secured CDN Script

Tags: javascript, karma-jasmine, cdn

I am tring to pre-load secured CDN script(company policy states all the urls be secured) for Karma-Jasmine test. Tried by creating element `const scriptElememtn = document.createElement('script');` and added the element to the document, `document.head.append(scriptElement);` Since it is secured, added the authentication cookie `document.cookie = "auth=0bec1d8f-e586-4e60-ace1-06935d5e0b41".` As the CDN is with company domain (**dev.company.com/components/v1**) and with karma it is **localhost**, it is not sending the cookie with the request.

My questions are

- Why the cookie is not sent in the CDN request.
- How can I pre-load the script?
- Can I download the script using **axios** library ?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved this by setting the proxies in **karma.conf.js** file. Inside the **src/test.js** file (init code for all the tests),

1. Set the `src` for the script element to **relative path** NOT the fully qualified path.
2. Set the `document.cookie`

Under `src/test.js`, add the below chunk,

```
const originalKarmaLoad = (window as any).__karma__.loaded;
 (window as any).__karma__.loaded = async function () {
      const wcplScript = document.createElement('script');
      const waitForLoad = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        wcplScript.onload = () => resolve(0);
        wcplScript.onerror = () => {
          console.error('Failed to load CDNs');
          reject();
        };
      });         
      document.cookie = `${cookie.name}=${cookie.value}`;
      wcplScript.src = '/cdn/lib/'; // use the relative path 
      wcplScript.async = false;
      wcplScript.type = 'module';
      document.body.insertBefore(wcplScript, document.body.lastChild);        
      await waitForLoad;
      originalKarmaLoad.call(this);
    };
```

Under `karma.conf.js`, set the proxies to point to the CDN,

```
{
.....
proxies: {
      '/cdn/lib/': {
        target: 'https://mycompany.com/cdn/lib',
        changeOrigin: true,
      },
    },
    proxyValidateSSL: false,
}
```